# Why Spark Structured Streaming window aggregation evaluates after each trigger

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

With Spark 2.2.0, I am reading data from Kafka having 2 columns "**textcol**" and "**time**". The "time" column has the latest processing time. I want to get the count of my unique values of "textcol" in fixed window duration of 20 seconds. My trigger duration is 10 seconds.

For example if in a 20 sec window duration, trigger1 has textcol=a and trigger2 has textcol=b, then I am expecting to have output as below after 20 sec

```
textcol    cnt
a          1
b          1
```

I used below code for dataset ds

```
ds.groupBy(functions.col("textcol"), 
                functions.window(functions.col("time"), "20 seconds"))
        .agg(functions.count("textcol").as("cnt"))
        .writeStream().trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
        .outputMode("update")
        .format("console").start();
```

But I am getting output twice due to 2 triggers after 20 sec

Trigger1:

```
textcol    cnt
a          1
```

Trigger2:

```
textcol    cnt
b          1
```

So why window does not aggregate the results and outputs after 20 sec, instead of triggering each time 10-10 sec?

Is there any other way to achieve it in spark structured streaming?

Answer (score -1):

change your `.outputMode("update")` to `.outputMode("complete")`